# Should refresh_token refresh non-expired access token

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, access-token, refresh-token

The answer may be obvious to some but I have not been able to find it stated explicitly in OAuth 2.0 spec. Supposing client is granted access token along with its expiration time and refresh token. What should happen if it for whatever reason issues refresh_token request while existing access token is still valid? Should the server respond with the old access token (with decreased expiration time) or generate new one without more ado?

Answer (score 0):

Since the server deals with awhile lot of access tokens have checks on the validity maybe more resource heavy than issuing a new one. I think it should just Issue you a new one if requested.

Another use case that comes to mind  is that the client might have requested a new token as the original access token is compromised.